# How do I extrude a circle outward

Tags: vertices

https://youtu.be/Uq4OLSRgSQE?t=202

In this video at 3:20 it says to extrude and when i try it doesn't extrude outwards it extrude forwards and I want it to extrude outwards. How do I do this???

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press E to extrude, then right click to reset the new geometry's position. Then press S to scale the geometry outwards. This is assuming the pivot is set to "median point"

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: since in the video he adds some extra geometry at the top before doing this, it might be best to set the 3D cursor as a pivot point instead (assuming it's already at the center of the sphere). The setting for it is at the top center of the 3D viewport.